# JS fractions for big numbers with no precision lose

Tags: javascript, math, precision, fractions, mathjs

Big numbers with fraction support:

I want to perform math operation with no precision loss.
How can I do it using JavaScript?
First I tried [decimal.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js/), but it does not preserve precision as you see in next example:

```
import {Decimal} from 'decimal.js';
const a1 = new Decimal(1);
const a2 = new Decimal(3);
console.log(a1.div(a2).toFraction()); // should be `1/3` but I get `33333333333333333333/100000000000000000000`
```

Next I tried [fraction.js](https://github.com/infusion/Fraction.js) but it does not work with large numbers, for example:

```
import Fraction from 'fraction.js';
const n1 = new Fraction("99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999");
const n2 = new Fraction("99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999990");
console.log(+(n1.sub(n2))) // should be 9, but I get 0
```

Are there any solutions to work with relative large numbers(lets say same as `decimal.js` supports) but with high precision(same as `fraction.js` supports).

I checked out that `mathjs` uses `fraction.js` under the hood, so no any advantages for large numbers:

```
import * as math from "mathjs";
const a1 = math.fraction(math.number("99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999"))
const a2 = math.fraction(math.number("99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999990"))
console.log(+(math.subtract(a1, a2))) // should be 9 but I get 0
```

Comment: You could write your own library for this. It's pretty simple.

Comment: @jabaa are you joking? decimal.js, fraction.js or mathjs are quite big libraries with lot of features... Writing such library for sure is not a simple task... And anyway it is better to have such library in the community than for every team to develop it separately

Comment: That first result looks like a bug (which I can replicate), since the docs say the first number is meant to be the numerator and the second the denominator. You might consider reporting it. (And perhaps fixing it. :-) )

Comment: It depends on your requirements. Writing code for the requirements in this question would take less than 2 hours. I wrote a similar library in my studies with much more features in some days.

Comment: Your question is either too broad, if you you're asking, how to write the code, or it asks for library recommendations, which is off-topic. If you have a question about one specific library, you could ask it here or on the GitHub page. Currently, you're asking about multiple libraries.

Answer (score 5):

Given that JavaScript has a BigInt data type, it is not so hard to implement the basic arithmetic operations yourself. Most logic will be needed in the constructor so to normalise the fraction (denominator should not be negative, numerator and denominator should be coprime) and deal with type conversion.

For example:

```js
class BigFraction {
    #n
    #d
    
    constructor(n, d=1n) {
        const abs = a => a < 0n ? -a : a;
        const gcd = (a, b) => b ? gcd(b, a % b) : a;
        const sign = a => a < 0n ? -1n : 1n;

        // Pass-through
        if (n instanceof BigFraction) return n;
        if (typeof d !== "bigint") throw "Second argument should be bigint when provided";
        if (typeof n !== "bigint") {
            if (arguments.length != 1) throw "Only one argument allowed when first is not a bigint"
            const s = String(n);
            const match = s.match(/^([+-]?\d+)(?:([.\/])(\d+))?$/);
            if (!match) throw `'${s}' not recognised as number`;
            if (match[2] == "/") {
                n = BigInt(match[1]);
                d = BigInt(match[3]);
            } else {
                n = BigInt(s.replace(".", ""));
                d = BigInt("1".padEnd((match[3]?.length ?? 0) + 1, "0"));
            }
        }
        // Normalize
        const factor = sign(n) * sign(d);
        n = abs(n);
        d = abs(d);
        const common = gcd(n, d);
        this.#n = factor * n / common;
        this.#d = d / common;
    }
    add(num) {
        const other = new BigFraction(num);
        return new BigFraction(this.#n * other.#d + other.#n * this.#d, this.#d * other.#d);
    }
    subtract(num) {
        const other = new BigFraction(num);
        return new BigFraction(this.#n * other.#d - other.#n * this.#d, this.#d * other.#d);
    }
    multiply(num) {
        const other = new BigFraction(num);
        return new BigFraction(this.#n * other.#n, this.#d * other.#d);
    }
    divide(num) {
        const other = new BigFraction(num);
        return new BigFraction(this.#n * other.#d, this.#d * other.#n);
    }
    inverse() {
        return new BigFraction(this.#d, this.#n);
    }
    sign() {
        return this.#n < 0n ? -1 : this.#n > 0n ? 1 : 0; 
    }
    negate() {
        return new BigFraction(-this.#n, this.#d);
    }
    compare(num) {
        return this.subtract(num).sign();        
    }
    toString() {
        const s = this.#n.toString();
        return this.#d != 1n ? s + "/" + this.#d : s;
    }
    valueOf() { // Conversion to number data type (float precision)
        return Number(this.#n) / Number(this.#d);
    }    
}

// Demo
var a = new BigFraction("12.34");
console.log("12.34 is " + a);
var b = a.add("-36/5");
console.log("12.34 - 36/5 is " + b);
var c = b.multiply("99128362832913233/9182");
console.log("(12.34 - 36/5) * (99128362832913233/9182) is " + c);
```

Answer (score 2):

That's more like a bug you found in `decimal.js`. If you manually provide the maximum denominator argument, it produces 1/3.

```js
const a1 = new Decimal(1);
const a2 = new Decimal(3);
console.log(a1.div(a2).toFraction(-1>>>1)); // maxD = largest 32-bit signed int
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/MikeMcl/decimal.js/decimal.js"></script>
```

https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js/issues seems to be where this could be reported.

Comment: Seems it is expected behavior https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js/issues/221#event-9363428154